# Return an expression inside a while loop - C language

Tags: c, while-loop, return

I know that calling a `return;` from a while exits from the loop, but what happens if you call `return VALUE` inside a loop? And firstly, is it possible?

EDIT: Strangely - but not so much because now I have the expected behaviour - reorganizing the function to show the code now the "return" all work as they should do.
Sorry for the silly question; I post the code anyway hoping it will be useful for someone with my same doubt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int function();

int main(){
printf("MAIN BEFORE FUNCTION\n");

    function();
    printf("MAIN AFTER FUNCTION\n");

    getch();
    return 0;
}

int function(){
    printf("FUNCTION ENTERED\n");
    int i = 1;
    if (i < 3){
        printf("IF ENTERED\n");
        return;
        printf("IF AFTER RETURN\n");

    }
    printf("FUNCTION AFTER IF\n");

    while (i < 3){
        printf("WHILE ENTERED\n");
        return;
        printf("WHILE AFTER RETURN\n");


    }
    printf("FUNCTION END\n");

    //return from function
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Same thing happens, but you return a value. The `return` statement works the same no matter where you put it. And note that `return` doesn't exit from the loop, but from the current *function*.

Comment: advice: to read up more on basics of C. return returns from function not only from loop

Comment: Why ask and not write a sample code to see for yourself?

Comment: Also, `return` is very much *not* a function, so you do not "call" it. It gets executed, like any other statement, if it's in the path of execution.

Comment: you may be thinking of `break;`, which exits a loop,, but only the _current_ loop (that is, if you have nested loops, you won't exit from all of them)

Comment: I tried myself on Visual Studio and I get that the simple "return;" doesn't return from the calling function but simply exits from the loop. The same appears to do the "return value": is there a reason why it behaves like that?

Comment: @Mebu115 I don't believe this, can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` statement will exit the current function, not just the loop it is in.

Whether you call `return` with or without a value depends on whether or not the function in question has a `void` return type.

Comment: I knew that return (whatever it is, with or without a value) should exit the current function, but in my trials it always exits the loop (or the if) in which is placed and not the main or the current function. My question arose from these evidences.

Comment: @Mebu115 could you please edit your original question and post some code to support your evidences?